# Why Do People Try Reconnecting Websockets After It Closes?

Tags: javascript, websocket, ws

I'm creating a real-time, multiplayer browser game using the ws websocket library in Javascript. I've seen multiple posts talking about the reconnection for their websockets. However, I don't understand why reconnecting the websocket is necessary. Are websocket connections inherently unstable and thus close regularly (~5mins)?

So my questions are, what are the main reasons people implement reconnection into their websockets? And what are the causes of the disconnections?

Comment: `Are websocket connections inherently unstable`.  No, but there not 100%, they can't be, like any network connection.

Comment: The player's wifi or modem could go out for moment or so.